# AsynchronousFileChannel throw java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, nio

I am playing with java nio 2 and I wrote a simple app that should create a file and write contents to it, but i am getting file not exists exception

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("jhkjhkhjkhkjhkjhkjhkjhkhkjhkjhkjh".getBytes());

    Path path = Paths.get("F:", "dummyFile.txt");

    try(AsynchronousFileChannel asynchronousFileChannel =
            AsynchronousFileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)) {
        Future<Integer> future = asynchronousFileChannel.write(buffer, 0);
        while (!future.isDone()) {
            System.out.println("waiting");
        }

        System.out.println(String.format("Done - bytes written %d", future.get()));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok , I found that i supposed to add the write option

```
AsynchronousFileChannel asynchronousFileChannel =
            AsynchronousFileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)
```